# How to get Order ID on product view.html

Tags: orders, magento-1, items

I'm trying to get all Order ID's for each Product ID.
So far I'm getting the Product Id with the following code:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $product->getId());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sales_order_items = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $_product->getId());
    $OrderIds = $sales_order_items->getColumnValues('order_id');
    $sales_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $OrderIds));
    foreach($sales_orders as $sales_order){
        echo $sales_order->getIncrementId();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$orders = array();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_id', array('eq' => $product->getId()))
    ->load();
foreach($collection as $orderItem) {
   $orders[$orderItem->getOrder()->getIncrementId()] = $orderItem->getOrder();   
}
```